# Ansible-playbook search for roles in the wrong directory! How to correct it?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

When I run the following ansible command:

```
$ ansible-playbook deploy/solo/wifi.yml -i inventories/solo
```

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR! the role 'solo/controller/wifi' was not found in /home/peng/git/uavops/deploy/roles:/home/peng/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/peng/git/uavops/deploy

The error appears to be in '/home/peng/git/uavops/deploy/wifi.yml': line 5, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - solo/controller/wifi
      ^ here
```

How did this happen? I invoke the `ansible-playbook` under the working directory `/home/peng/git/uavops`. Yet ansible-playbook ignores it and try to find the roles in directory `/home/peng/git/uavops/deploy`.

How do I tell ansible to locate the right role directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ansible looks for roles in two locations:

```
 roles/ #   in a directory called relative to the playbook file

/etc/ansible/roles
```

If you store your roles in a different location, set the `roles_path` configuration option so Ansible can find your roles. Checking shared roles into a single location makes them easier to use in multiple playbooks. See [Configuring](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-roles-path) Ansible for details about managing settings in `ansible.cfg`.

Alternatively, you can call a role with a fully qualified path:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  roles:
    - role: '/path/to/my/roles/common'
```

You can set `role_path` in your inventory file to tell ansible where to search role.

In your case,

1. you should move your roles inside a directory called `roles` at same level as the playbook.
2. Full path of the role or

   roles:
   - home/peng/git/uavops/deploy/solo/controller/wifi
3. use `role_path` to point to desired location.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the working directory ... Sounds really difficult to organize

Comment: I typically keep all the roles in one directory  and keep softlink to that directory in all the playbook directory.  This keep things very simple and organized

Comment: Thanks for the research! After digging in [the official role docs about the structure of roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure) which has absolutely NO `tests` dir - and the [official ansible-galaxy docs about the `ansible-galaxy role init` command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/dev_guide.html#creating-roles-for-galaxy) which mentions a `tests` dir, I was completely confused. Since the generated `test.yml` inside didn't even work!